# How use batch with role-based security

Tags: glassfish, role-based-access-control

Sorry for my english.... May be someone help me find information about using batch job with role-based security in glassfish server?
When I invoke the method from EJB :

```
@Override
    @RolesAllowed({"root_role", "admin_role", "user_role"})
    public void execute() {
        BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().start(STATISTIC_JOB_NAME, new Properties());
    }
```

I get exception like this:
  javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation

My job class:

```
@Dependent
@Named(value = "StatisticJob")
public class StatisticJob extends AbstractBatchlet {

    @EJB
    private StatisticFacadeLocal sfl;


    @Override
    public String process() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("StatisticJob.process()");
        List<StatisticPortEntity> spes = sfl.findAll();
        if (spes != null && !spes.isEmpty()) {
            for (StatisticPortEntity spe : spes) {
               System.out.println(spe);
            }
        } else {
            return "Statistic list is empty.";
        }
        return "StatisticJob.proccess is done.";
    }
}
```

How use role-based security with batch? 
Thank's!

Comment: I resolve this problem independently. I add security annotation to EJB method and it's work!